# Join on equal substring?

Tags: mysql, join, substring

I have a database of games and prices, in which I recently found yet another issue. There are some games which appear in the database twice - once for the PC version and once for the Mac version. If there are two such versions of a game, I don't need the mac version in my database. If there is ONLY a mac version of the game, however, I would like to keep it.

The issue was made a bit simpler for me since all games that also have a mac version will use the exact same name plus a small snippet at the end to indicate it's for mac. This might take the form "Left 4 Dead 2 (Mac)", "Left 4 Dead 2 Mac", or "Left 4 Dead 2 [Mac Download]".

To try and find these entries I created the following query:

```
SELECT *
FROM `gamelist` g1
JOIN `gamelist` g2
ON
    SUBSTR(g1.`title`,0,20) = SUBSTR(g2.`title`,0,20)
    AND
    g1.`title`<>g2.`title`
WHERE
    (g1.`amazon_id` IS NOT NULL AND g2.`amazon_id` IS NOT NULL)
    OR (g1.`steam_id` IS NOT NULL AND g2.`steam_id` IS NOT NULL)
    OR (g1.`impulse_id` IS NOT NULL AND g2.`impulse_id` IS NOT NULL)
    ...
```

The idea should be fairly straightforward. The issue is that the `SUBSTR()` didn't seem to work at all. In a database with roughly 8,000 entries it returned about 64 million results. Obviously it's completely skipping the `SUBSTR(g1.title,0,20) = SUBSTR(g2.title,0,20)` line and joining the rows any time `g1.title<>g2.title`

How can I join on equal substrings like this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

SUBSTR(), in the manner you're using it, is one-indexed, not zero-indexed.  You want

```
SUBSTR(g1.`title`,1,20) = SUBSTR(g2.`title`,1,20)
```

Comment: +1 nice spot. For clarity, it wasn't *skipping* it was a coding error.